# I want to connect to livesql oracle without installing oracle to execute queries and get results

Tags: python, database, oracle

I am using python , and oracle 11g express edition. 
Sometimes 11g express edition giving wrong results . So i want to go for live sql to get correct results.

Please help is there any way to connect to live sql oracle without installing oracle .

```
drop table t5;
create table t5 (A int not null, b  int not null,c int,  primary key(a,b));
insert into t5 values (0,0,0);
insert into t5 values (0,200,NULL);
insert into t5 values (1,1,1);
insert into t5 values (1,201,NULL);
insert into t5 values (2,2,2);
insert into t5 values (2,202,NULL);
insert into t5 values (3,3,3);
insert into t5 values (3,203,NULL);
insert into t5 values (4,4,4);
insert into t5 values (4,204,NULL);
drop table t6;
create table t6 (A int not null, b  int not null,c int,  primary key(a,b));
insert into t6 values (0,0,0);
insert into t6 values (0,200,NULL);
insert into t6 values (1,1,1);
insert into t6 values (1,201,NULL);
insert into t6 values (2,2,2);
insert into t6 values (2,202,NULL);
insert into t6 values (3,3,3);
insert into t6 values (3,203,NULL);
insert into t6 values (4,4,4);
insert into t6 values (4,204,NULL);
select * from t5  right  join t6 on t5.a=-1 and t5.a=t6.a where t5.a<0 or t5.a=t6.a  ;

(None, None, None, 3, 203, None)
(None, None, None, 3, 3, 3)
(None, None, None, 1, 201, None)
(None, None, None, 1, 1, 1)
(None, None, None, 2, 202, None)
(None, None, None, 2, 2, 2)
(None, None, None, 0, 200, None)
(None, None, None, 0, 0, 0)
(None, None, None, 4, 204, None)
(None, None, None, 4, 4, 4)
---  10 row(s) selected. 
Actually expecting  0 rows
```

I actually used 11g express edition which is installed in my system.
by comparing results live sql oracle giving correct results (https://livesql.oracle.com/)

Comment: By LiveSQL do you mean the Oracle cloud testbed application? If so, you don't need to install Oracle to access it , you just need a (free) TechNet account. However, it's not intended for use as a persistent data store, so it's probably not what you want. Perhaps you should explain more about your actual problem, *11g xe giving wrong results*.

Comment: Please demonstrate the wrong results in 11g vs 12c. I'm guessing the database isn't wrong.

Comment: Please execute above queries in live sql , you will get 0 rows .

Answer (score 2):

LiveSQL isn't a database you can connect to.

It's a database running in the Oracle Cloud, that you can borrow for running any Oracle SQL or PL/SQL - via a browser/web interface.

If you want a local copy of Oracle to work with w/o having to install or maintain an Oracle Database, then our [VirtualBox appliance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html) will do the trick.

You just install VirtualBox, download the appliance, import it, and click the 'start' button.

When it's running, you'll have a copy of Oracle Database 12cr2 running, with some sample data, Oracle SQL Developer & APEX already installed and ready to go.

[image]

I talk about it [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/03/oracle-database-12c-release-2-is-now-available-and-so-is-our-new-virtualbox-appliance/) in more detail.

When you're done with it, just remove the files. No registry to clean up, nothing to uninstall.

And it's all free - for learning/educational purposes.

Comment: Thank you  but i need a python program to connect to oracle database either to virtual box or directly. so that i can  connect and will get results.

Comment: we can't write your python program for you, but if you grab the virtualbox appliance, you'll have a database your python app can connect to

Comment: Thank you can you share which modules i need to use in python to connect to virtual box appliance,as of now i am using cx_Oracle

Comment: are you asking how to define your python connection or are you asking how to address your oracle database that's running on the virtualbox linux image?

Comment: how to address your oracle database that's running on the virtualbox linux image

Comment: localhost:1521/orcl

Comment: there's a port fwd defined in the vm, fwds traffic from your machine 1521 to the linux image 1521